# How do I receive a revert message using go-ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, abi, solc, golang

How do I receive a revert message using go-ethereum?

```
receipt, err := bind.WaitMined(context.Background(), client, tx)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Errorf(err)
}
fmt.Println(receipt.Status)
```

Now I can only get status. I use abigen to call smart contract methods

Answer (score 1):

I use something like that, it redo the transaction as a call and that way you get the failing message.

```golang
func GetFailingMessage(client ethclient.Client, hash common.Hash) (string, error) {
    tx, _, err := client.TransactionByHash(context.Background(), hash)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    from, err := types.Sender(types.NewEIP155Signer(tx.ChainId()), tx)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    msg := ethereum.CallMsg{
        From:     from,
        To:       tx.To(),
        Gas:      tx.Gas(),
        GasPrice: tx.GasPrice(),
        Value:    tx.Value(),
        Data:     tx.Data(),
    }

    res, err := client.CallContract(context.Background(), msg, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return string(res), nil
}
```